# Adjust labels of second Y axis on the right of the plot

Tags: r, plot, scale

I have plotted the below graph but the cannot adjust the labels of the seconds Y axis. Does anybody have any idea how that is possible?

Also my right hand Y axis has limit from 1 to 14 *10^8 but when I set it, it only goes from zero to 1.4. Cannot find why!

Here is the code I used to make the plot

```
fdic <- data.frame(matrix(scan(text ="1   16.70833333 1329877000
2   17.20370370 1118256000
3   16.61111111 1047726000
4   19.05555556 972202000
5   15.50925926 269648386
6   0.07407407  248606000
7   3.00925926  220576899
8   5.83796296  188132575"), 8, 3, byrow = T))
colnames(fdic) <- c("id", "botnets_per_wk", "Deposits")

plot <- plot(fdic$id, fdic$botnets_per_wk, pch=16, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,25), xlab="", ylab="",
type="l",col="dark blue")
axis(2, col="black",las=1) 
mtext("Average # of botnets attacking banks per week",side=2,line=2.5)
box()
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fdic$id, fdic$Deposits, pch=15,  xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(1,1400000000),
axes=FALSE, type="l", col="red")
mtext("Deposits (USD, logged)",side=4,col="red",line=4)
axis(4, ylim=c(1,1400000000), col="black",col.axis="black",las=1)
axis(1,at = seq(1, 50, by = 1))
mtext("bank",side=1,col="black",line=2.5)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Average # of botnets attacking banks per week","Deposits"),
text.col=c("black","red"),pch=c(16,15),col=c("black","red"))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the labels. They look fine. Can you explain? The right hand axis is limited at the top because the second plot is fit in the "window" of the first plot. Post your code, it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: @what, the axis (y) label on the right is not there while i put it there. will update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that "1.4" you see is `1.4e+09`, the scientific notation for 1.4 billion. Use `options(scipen=999)` to turn off scientific notation in R (this resets after reboot of R) and then adjust the left margins with `par(mai=c(...))` for the long numbers to be completely visible:

```
fdic <- data.frame(matrix(scan(text ="1   16.70833333 1329877000
2   17.20370370 1118256000
3   16.61111111 1047726000
4   19.05555556 972202000
5   15.50925926 269648386
6   0.07407407  248606000
7   3.00925926  220576899
8   5.83796296  188132575"), 8, 3, byrow = T))
colnames(fdic) <- c("id", "botnets_per_wk", "Deposits")

options(scipen=999)

par(mai = c(1, 1, 1, 2))
plot <- plot(fdic$id, fdic$botnets_per_wk, pch=16, axes=FALSE, ylim=c(0,25), xlab="", ylab="", type="l",col="dark blue")
axis(2, col="black",las=1) 
mtext("Average # of botnets attacking banks per week",side=2,line=2.5)
box()
par(new=TRUE)
plot(fdic$id, fdic$Deposits, pch=15,  xlab="", ylab="", ylim=c(1,1400000000), axes=FALSE, type="l", col="red")
mtext("Deposits (USD, logged)",side=4,col="red",line=4)
axis(4, ylim=c(1,1400000000), col="black",col.axis="black",las=1)
axis(1,at = seq(1, 50, by = 1))
mtext("bank",side=1,col="black",line=2.5)
legend("topleft",legend=c("Average # of botnets attacking banks per week","Deposits"), text.col=c("black","red"),pch=c(16,15),col=c("black","red"))
```

[image]

But actually I would leave the `1.4`-scale and label that axis with "Deposits (**in billion** US Dollar, logged)", because those long numbers with the many zeros are hard to read (I had to put my finger on them and count the zeros, and you don't want your readers to have to do that).